# How to prefetch HTTP requests in squid?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, cache, squid

I'm looking for a (set of) configuration directive(s) or workarounds to make `squid` 4.x prefetch HTTP requests (e.g. of `a` link elements on HTML sites). I know about the downsides and that this doesn't too much sense with today's traffic and the natur HTTP 1.1 is used.

My research so far:

- http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Prefetching-HTTP-GET-requests-but-under-HTTPS-td4665838.html which explains the downsides mentioned above, but only recommends the `squid-prefetch` package which I don't find for Ubuntu 15.10.
- The search of the squid wiki at squid-cache.org gives me 404 error. I might share my research here as soon as this is fixed (staff is informed).
- https://serverfault.com/questions/478734/prefetch-and-cache-http-requests-on-squid-or-any-proxy-server which only covers the client side and not the server configuration

I'm happy for solutions dealing with HTTP requests only, but would mind if they cover HTTPS (with SSL bumping configured in `squid`) as well.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and `squid` 4.0.1.

Comment: make any headway on this?

Comment: No. You could place a bounty if you'd like to see progress on this.

Comment: ah. I've been dealing with the authentication side of squid for the past few weeks, was passingly curious. Good luck.